# How to set action for button on this custom dialog?

Tags: blackberry, customdialog

I make a custom Dialog like as :

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
     public CustomDialog(String s) {
    super(s, new String[] {"View","Cancel"}, new int [] {1,2}, 1,         Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION), Manager.FOCUSABLE);

    }
```

How can I set **action** for "View button" and " Cancel button " ?
I searched and not found what I have to do .
Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code.. this might help you..

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;

public class CustomAlertDialog extends Dialog {


    public CustomAlertDialog() {
        super("Your Custom message for Dialoug" , null, null, Dialog.DISCARD, null, Dialog.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

        ButtonField view = null;

        view = new ButtonField("view") {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            // do what ever you want
            return true;
            }

            protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
            // do what ever you want
            return true;
            }
        };

        ButtonField cancel = null;
        cancel = new ButtonField("Cancel") {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            // do what ever you want
            return true;
            }

            protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
            // do what ever you want
            return true;
            }
        };
    hfm.add(view);
    hfm.add(cancel);

    this.add(hfm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, this code is very useful . But I use action close() for "Cancel Button " , I have to click **2 times** to close dialog. I worked on Simulator. Can you explain why ?

Comment: Oh, it is problem of simulator, I changed simualotor and it work well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `DialogClosedListener` to your `CustomDialog` using `Dialog.setDialogClosedListener()`. When someone clicks either of the buttons, the `DialogClosedListener.dialogClosed()` method will be called and the button index will be passed as the `choice` parameter.

Comment: This works if you supply an Object array of choices, but if you are using custom button fields, the returned `choice` is always -1.